# Change the value of window.localStorage in JavascriptCore (redefining un-configurable property from C/Obj-C APIs)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit, javascriptcore

The WebKit framework in OSX has a broken localStorage implementation which doesn't persist stored data (data isn't there after application restart).

So i've implemented an alternative LocalStorage object.

However, I can't assign `window.localStorage = myLocalStorage` because `localStorage` is defined as non-writeable, and non-configurable.

I can't find a way to override such property in JavascriptCore, by using the C/Obj-C APIs. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't override it directly but you can use StorageItem to override it. But over-ridding storage item will override both session storage and localStorage

```
var _setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem; // first assign it to some variable
Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value) { 
   if (this === window.localStorage) {
     // play with localstorage here
   } else {
     // fallback
     _setItem.apply(this, arguments);
   }
}
```

Second ways is to override with `__proto__` property but this is not standard, it is supported in firefox, chrom, opera not sure about others

```
localStorage.__proto__ = Object.create(Storage.prototype);
```

Check this example where they have wriiten to override default to store JSON objects

https://gist.github.com/danott/942522

Comment: nice solution, however it won't work when assigning to properties like `localStorage["foo"] = "bar"`

Comment: With this assignment localStorage["foo"] = "bar", it comes inside this block if (this === window.localStorage) {, but it stores the value in localStorage also. I can't think of any other way

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage if its useful for that. The problem is that there is no proper api documentation for localstorage

Comment: It is fully documented and there is even a spec for it :) http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0 . This solution is nice, but incomplete ;)